# dynamically add pictures to gallery widget

Tags: android

Is there a good way to add new image resources(from SD card) to a gallery widget at runtime?

Comment: Are you parsing any site and want to add images dynamically?

Comment: Not quite, just from an SD card.

Answer (score 28):

"new image resources"?

Image resources are a part of /res/drawable folder inside your .apk application package. You can not add "new" image resources during runtime.

Is there some other use case you had in mind?

**Edited after posters explanation:**

You have to add media files to Media Store in order to be seen by gallery widget. Use MediaScanner. I use this convenient wrapper in my code:

```
public class MediaScannerWrapper implements  
MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
    private String mPath;
    private String mMimeType;

    // filePath - where to scan; 
    // mime type of media to scan i.e. "image/jpeg". 
    // use "*/*" for any media
    public MediaScannerWrapper(Context ctx, String filePath, String mime){
        mPath = filePath;
        mMimeType = mime;
        mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(ctx, this);
    }

    // do the scanning
    public void scan() {
        mConnection.connect();
    }

    // start the scan when scanner is ready
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPath, mMimeType);
        Log.w("MediaScannerWrapper", "media file scanned: " + mPath);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // when scan is completes, update media file tags
    }
}
```

Then instantiate `MediaScannerWrapper` and start it with `scan()`. You could tweak it to handle more than one file at the time. Hint: pass List of File paths, and then loop around `mConnection.scanFile`.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about images stored on the external storage.

Comment: So, how does this connect to a gallery widget to display?

Comment: Gallery widget displays all files that are added to Media Store.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to update apps that use the info... For example, downloading a mp3 and running this code will scan it, but not add to the default media player. To do that, you need context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));   as described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300137/how-can-i-refresh-mediastore-on-android

Answer (score 1):

**Send broadcast to  `MediaStore Content Provider` when you add a file**

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageAdded)));
```

**Working for devices before KitKat**

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
              Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23078323/1925394)

Working in Lolipop and should also solve kitkat issues.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,"file path");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
mContext.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```

Add Permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```