# Why does File.Exists return false?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm querying all images on the Android device as such:

```
string[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data, 
            MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id };
string orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id;
var imagecursor = ManagedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, columns, null, null, orderBy);
for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++) {
    imagecursor.MoveToPosition(i);
    Paths[i]= imagecursor.GetString(dataColumnIndex);
    Console.WriteLine(Paths[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.Exists(Paths[i]));
}
```

The problem is that the output shows that some files don't exist. Here's a sample output:

> /storage/sdcard0/Download/On-Yom-Kippur-Jews-choose-different-shoes-VSETQJ6-x-large.jpg
>   False
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/397277_10151250943161341_876027377_n.jpg
>   False
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/Roxy_Cottontail_&_Melo-X_Present..._Some_Bunny_Love's_You.jpg
>   False
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/album-The-Rolling-Stones-Some-Girls.jpg
>   True
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/some-people-ust-dont-appreciate-fashion[1].jpg
>   True
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/express.gif
>   True
>   ...
>   /storage/sdcard0/Download/some-joys-are-expressed-better-in-silence.JPG
>   False

How is this possible? I downloaded these images myself from the internet! They should exist in disk.

Comment: What API level are you compiling with and do you have the correct EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions?

Comment: I am targeting framework 2.3. I didn't have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but I did have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Adding the READ one yields the same results

Comment: I am using the Android Support V4

Comment: Have you scanned your downloads directory with MediaScannerConnection?

Comment: I think the problem was that those images were corrupted. I went into the gallery and saw that the affected images did not have a width and height set. Furthermore, some of the images were not displaying on full screen mode. I deleted those images and downloaded more and now File.Exists return true for all images.

Comment: I was wrong. The problem is now happening again! What could be the problem? And also, I have since changed the code to use the LoaderManager as ManagedQuery is deprecated.

Comment: @MorrisonChang no I have not. What do I gain from using the MediaScannerConnection?

Comment: I might be making assumptions so perhaps you can flesh out your question further by describing what you want to accomplish and what you think your code is doing.

Comment: I basically wrote my own gallery. I'm displaying all the images in a listview so we can implement multi select of images.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a LoaderMananger/ManagedQuery to query the Media Content Provider in Android. A Content Provider is just a way to access a particular SQLite database from different apps. If you use the Android provided Media Content Provider you'll have to update it 'manually' by using MediaScannerConnection to add in the new files that you've placed, as the 'service' may or may not update internally while your app is running.

Here are some related SO questions:
[Scan Android SD card for new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753252/scan-android-sd-card-for-new-files)
and [Trigger mediascanner on specific path (folder), how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414955/trigger-mediascanner-on-specific-path-folder-how-to) but I don't recommend the answer of globally scanning your SD card.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Samsung device, all those paths may be incorrect !

// Put this in your code and then log the 'external' string to see

```
String external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

if you get say: /storage/sdcard0/

Then Samsung themselves say you have to do this lame append (I claim they broke the API :)

```
external = external + "/external_sd/";
```

I am not certain this applies to downloads or not, but I suspect it affects ALL similar sub-paths.

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=162934&messageNumber=1381&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=TITLE&searchText=sdcard

[EDIT:] Caveat Emptor !  Even this does not work on some Samsung devices. ARRRRGGGGGG