# How to trigger media scanner programatically?

Tags: android, android-file

I am writing a media player application. Implementing SDCard refresh option programatically.The following code is not working in KITKAT version to get newly added/renamed/deleted audio, video files.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug with KitKat, as reported by [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818151/1367571). The issue has been posted in the official [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68056).

For a more complete overview of the problem, please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23078323/1367571).