# Best place/method for storing music

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage

I have an application that will be managing media files such as music and movies, and I'd like to allow the user to choose where these are kept when they are downloaded/synced.

This will rule out simply storing them as application data using a cache or data directory, but I'm confused as to what the best method to do this now is in light of KitKat's changes to how external/secondary storage is treated.

Is there now a preferred method for creating root level folders such `/mnt/sdcard/Music`, and is it possible to do this in a way that's fully backwards compatible (ideally without having to use reflection check for and execute methods). Ideally I'd like to be able to have a user simply select a storage volume and I'll use a default sub-directory on that, with an advanced option for the user to select somewhere more specific, are both possible?

The folders also shouldn't be private, as I'd like other apps to still be able to access them to play the files stored within (i.e - I don't want to implement my own media player).

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157724/dynamically-add-pictures-to-gallery-widget (The question talks about images, but the answer works for **any** media file)

Comment: I think that's more about scanning existing files, whereas I'm more concerned with storing new files (e.g - synced from another device/computer), but in a common location so that other apps can access it. For example, my phone has the Music+ music player, my app would download music somewhere such that I, as the user, can then play it in Music+, and easily locate the file(s) for pointing apps to them specifically etc.