# android not show image that I save from my custom camera app

Tags: android, image, camera, cursor, gallery

I created custom camery and gallery from SDCard.
I successfully created both. But After I saved a image from MyCameraActivity, It is not shown my custom gallery gridView.

MyCustomGalleryActivity is using Cursor to get thumbnail image from SDcard.

Why does it not show the image that was saved from myCamera?

The image is shown at default gallery application.

Help me plz...

Comment: Without putting your code of the gallery we won't be able to help at all..

Comment: show your code for both saving pictures to sd card and when fetching them for gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to force android to do re scanning of media files other wise those files appears after you root device
you can use following link to force scanning of media files
[dynamically add pictures to gallery widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157724/dynamically-add-pictures-to-gallery-widget)