# ArrayList of images to GridView

Tags: java, android

I have a list of images in my ArrayList, I would like to display them in GridView, the same way the example is over here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

```
ArrayList<String> myPhotos = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This specific example shows how to do it with drawables what I have already included in my project, how to do it with images that I know full path and are located in SD Card?

Or is there other good and easy way to display the array of images from sd card?

Comment: For opening files located in the SD card, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5453753/862629