# getExternalStorageDirectory() is not recognized

Tags: android, mobile-application

```
private Context mContext;


 public Upload(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath) 
    {

        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        String outPath = mContext.getExternalStorageDirectory(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"a1.jpg";
```

Error:The method getExternalStorageDirectory() is undefined for the type Context

```
String outPath = mContext.getExternalFilesDir("mnt/sdcard").getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"a1.jpg";
```

works fine..

Comment: Its static for the environment class not context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
String outPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"a1.jpg";
```

instead of

```
String outPath = mContext.getExternalStorageDirectory(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"a1.jpg";
```

Answer (score 3):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` is not defined for Context type. It is defined in [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class and it is a static method.