# How to delete the data from sdcard while android application is uninstalling?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-install-apk

I have an application which saves magazines on sdcard. Now i want to delete all the downloaded magazines while application is being uninstall.
Is there any way to do that problematically. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create file using getExternalStorageDirectory() method it will delete the files belong to your application while delete application

see the below linl for creating file using that

[Android how to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory)

Answer (score 0):

while uninstalling any app from android phone..It provides an option "clear data" I think doing it would automatically remove your datas if you have created it through code.

Comment: The option "clear data" clears the internal memory associated to the application not the external.

Answer (score 0):

Please check link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

you save data folder: /Android/data//cache/
The  is your Java-style package name, such as "com.example.android.app".

When uninstall application, data clear.