# Downloading and displaying an image

Tags: android, image, download

I want to download an image from server, save it on the SD card, and show it.
I wrote that code, but it doesn't work - there are no bugs, but I see only a black screen instead of the image.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyTask mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute();

    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    File file = new File("/sdcard/askeroid/logos/1_mobile.png");  
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");  
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

}
class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://ed.sadko.mobi/logo/logo_1mobile.png");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/askeroid/logos/1_mobile.png");

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  return null;
}
```

}

Comment: "there are no bugs, but I see only a black screen instead of the image" -- sounds like a bug to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't wait for the end of the download before moving to next activity.

I suggest you use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - download the image using in `doInBackground` and start next activity in `onPostExecute`.

Something like:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override protected Long doInBackground(Void ... urls) {
        // download the image
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // start new activity...
    }
};
task.execute();
```

Also, please note that the path to the SD card may vary between different devices. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory) to see how to access it properly.

Comment: Also, the linked documentation to AsyncTask has a full code sample.

Comment: @Binyamin, i've changed my code, but it still doesn't wirk - i edited my question, there is new code

Comment: Sorry for the late response. First, as digitaljoel wrote, you don't write to the output stream from the input stream, you only create them, so you don't write anything. Second, you need to start the new activity from `onPostExecute()`, not right after calling `execute`

Answer (score 1):

+1 for The answer to use AsyncTask, it makes threading on android super easy.  Another problem is that you open the `InputStream` and the `OutputStream` but you never actually read anything from the input nor do you write anything to the output, so the file on your sdcard is going to be empty.

Comment: +1 Someone told me a few days ago that if someone always uses a hammer, everything look like nails to him. I really overlooked this tiny-tiny issue :P

Comment: @BinyaminSharet You should add my info to your answer so the best answer is all in one place and the submitter can accept your more complete answer.

Comment: like @BinyaminSharet said, you should start the next intent in the onPostExecute of the AsyncTask implementation.  You are still starting the next intent immediately after starting the thread so the image download doesn't complete.  You also are still not writing the image to the file system because you never use the streams you open.