# Android 4.4 files list issue

Tags: android, android-file

I tried to get files in `/sdcard/` folder, but it throws `NullPointerException`

Then I tried to get folders in `/` path it returns

```
40
factory
usbdisk
sdcard
storage
config
cache
acct
vendor
d
etc
mnt
ueventd.tuna.rc
ueventd.rc
ueventd.goldfish.rc
system
sys
sepolicy
seapp_contexts
sbin
res
... and others
```

When I do this in 4.3 project it works well!

**UPDATE**

code in 4.4 which not work

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] files = file.listFiles();
Debugger.info(files.length); // NullPointerExcepton
for(File f : files){
    Debugger.info(f.getName());
}
```

Comment: Give us the value of `new File("/sdcard/").exists()`! If it is false, make sure it exists... Also, check your permissions...

Comment: I have `/sdcard/` path!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) site states (in the important behaviour changes in KitKat)

> **If your app reads from external storage...**
>
> Your app can not read shared files on the external storage when
>   running on Android 4.4, unless your app has the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   permission. That is, files within the directory returned by
>   getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() are no longer accessible without
>   the permission. However, if you need to access only your app-specific
>   directories, provided by getExternalFilesDir(), then you do not need
>   the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

So make sure you give the above permision. Also, if you are using a device with multiple sd cards you may run in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619094/1482726).

Answer (score 2):

You should not hard code the sdcard path in your code.
Instead, you should get the sdcard path by

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Comment: it's cause `NullPointerExeception` too