# Environment.getExternalStorageState() returning errors

Tags: android

As a matter of course in my applications, before I read/write anything to the external storage I check [Environment.getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29)

I'd always assumed it worked as intended in my applications that occasionally write to the storage, but with my most recent application (which is highly dependent on the storage system), I check this as the application starts and I toast an error to the user if something is wrong (state does not equal [MEDIA_MOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_MOUNTED)).

I'm getting a number of reports from users receiving this error toast due to [MEDIA_UNMOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_UNMOUNTED).

BUT, there is no removable sdcard to mount/unmount and most puzzling of all, other applications are using the storage regardless.... Which leaves me to conclude they must be testing this another way?

I've only found one [post that may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619094/1256219) to the cause, but if you scroll up to the answer above, there are 13 upvotes for a comment reminding users to check the media is mounted correctly first!

So, I'm confused and wondering if someone is aware of an issue?

Comment: What exactly is the returned string?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 For the user I'm currently debugging with, it's `MEDIA_UNMOUNTED`. Others have commented on the Play Store, but not replied as to their specific error code

Comment: isExternalStorageRemovable() ?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 Not with this particular user. I'm uncertain of the devices that others are experiencing problems with though.

Comment: OMG. The only thing that comes to my mind is to try{} to check if there are any files under the mount point, and if they are there, and if you can create a file...

Comment: Does your application have permissions to access the external storage? IIRC they changed the policy somehow... but i do not remember what exactly.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 I had considered trying{} to write an empty file to the storage, to double check, but due to the linked answer above it seems as though some devices will also fail on `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, so that doesn't appear fool-proof... Edit: Yes, definitely has the correct permissions.

Comment: NB: **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** _Added in API level 16_

Comment: @18446744073709551615 Thanks - but if you have the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` you are automatically granted the read permission.

Comment: And you believe them?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 - Yes... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: You already see their bug. They (the Google) wanted to grant that permission, but they may have failed to do that consistently. In the absence of better ideas, I would try that second permission.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 - I understand your sceptical logic, but there is nothing in the logcat of the user that shows a permission denial has occurred. More importantly, the call to `getExternalStorageState()` does not require either permission.

Comment: Hmmm, while searching for something else I find out that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#KITKAT mentions in the whatsnew list: _The READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is now always enforced._ and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE says that the rules depend on the version and are really complex.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that, even without a removable SD card, the internal storage the device gives out by these APIs can still be mounted to a connected computer instead of the apps.

Answer (score 0):

User may forbidden the permission: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.