# FileNotFoundException when try to upload a image in AsynTask thread

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask, filenotfoundexception

Following are my code in `AsynTask` thread:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM/IMG_20140210_130057.jpg");
 boolean exist=f.exists(); //debug result exist=false.
```

This code fires `FileNotFoundException` but the file is there.

I have already added following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: try printing out the file path you're building.

Comment: have you seen that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Comment: Try to add the permission to read external storage.

Comment: Thank you all. After serveral trying. I found the problems is in the AsynTask . Because when i get the File code in the MainActivity UI thread, file.exists return true.


 But in AsynTask execution, file.exists return false. How can it be like this?

Comment: Thanks all one more time. I finally get the problem that, in AsyncTask, when passing parameter from List<String> to List, when convert object Back to String, it automationcally added [/mnt/sdcard...] ,this cause the FileNotFound exception. Sorry for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you forgot to call `getAbsolutePath()` method ?

Try this way,

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/DCIM/IMG_20140210_130057.jpg");
```

Comment: Tried, file.exists() still return false. Thank you.

Comment: @cc5zhenhua for which device you are testing ?

Comment: You're the first guest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
File.separator
```

instead of '/' character that might help

Comment: hey look sometime .jpg, .jpeg, .JPG , seems different make sure with the extension of the file

Comment: Thank you. I found that in MAIN activity thread, file.exists()return true but in AsycnTask's execution, file.exists()return false.

So the problem is a high possibility related with the AsycnTask.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also, try to log the file path.

```
Log.d("Path:",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"DCIM/IMG_20140210_130057.jpg");
```

Comment: THe path in the log is: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/IMG_20140210_130057.jpg.
The file just be in the same location.