# How to read file from sdcard and display the text?

Tags: android, file

I'm new to Android development and I want to replace the file in TextView with text from file on external storage and show it in textView1. I searched many questions, but the solutions didn't work for me. Thanks for help. Here is my code:

Text View in fragment_profile:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/nick"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

And this is the activity:

```
package com.tom411.pyzdit;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
    File file = new File(dir,"/PyzdIt/name.txt");   

    if(file.exists())  
    {   
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();  

        try {  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
            String line;  

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
                text.append(line);  
                text.append('\n');  
            }
            br.read();
            br.close();
        }  
        catch (IOException e) {  
        }  
        tv.setText(text);  
    } 
}   

public void Back(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: may be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code yet but the first thing that I would check for is the **access to ExternalStorage** . Maybe you have got to put a `<uses-permission>` entry in app manifest to allow access to the external storage **(android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).**

Comment: Thanks, I added the check for external storage and the activity is now not FC, but it still don't show the content of file name.txt. I have got READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

use this code its works fine :

```
File logFile = new File("sdcard/text.txt");
               if (logFile.exists())
               {
                  try
                  { FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(logFile);
                        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                        String aDataRow = "";
                        String aBuffer = "";
                        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";}
                        text.setText(aBuffer); 
                        myReader.close(); 
                      logFile.createNewFile();
                  } 
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }

               }
```

and be sure use the permission on manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: No, it still doesn't show the content of name.txt(after rename)

Comment: any error ? add WRITE permission to manifest i used that code a lot  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>