# Android eclipse FileOutputStream FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, string, utf-8, filenotfoundexception

I want to save some Bytes with the FileOutputStream but it says the file name is too long (/mnt/sdcard/3m.png)..

I get the file name in UTF-8 coded Bytes, I create a String like:

```
String FilePath = new String(FilePathBytes, 0, FilePathBytes.length, "UTF-8");
```

This FilePath String throws the FileNotFoundException, if I set the FilePath directly

```
FilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/3m.png";
```

it saves my file..

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem - The Length of the string FilePath after the encoding from the bytes is: 65532 - That's the size of the FilePathBytes where I create the string from...

So it's to long (File name too long, FileNotFoundException), but the string is full of empty chars.. Now I try to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to write to the file :

```
public static void writeToFile(File file, String string) {
    file.mkdirs(); // if your folder doesn't exist, this method (mkdirs) will create it.
    FileOutputStream out;
    PrintStream prt;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        prt = new PrintStream(out);
        prt.println(string);
        prt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Write error");
    }
}
```

And how can you call this method ?

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/3m.png"); // or where is your file
String text = "Your message or bytes which will save to file";
writeToFile(file, text);
```

Comment: I think the problem is not how I save the file (because it's working if I set the FilePath directly) - The problem is the decoding from bytes to string..