# Getting error while uploading file from real device to server

Tags: android, asyncfileupload

I am getting an error while file uploading to the server from the real device. All are working well in the emulator as I switch to real device get an error.

Here is code,

Function to choose a file from the device

```
private void showFileChooser(int index) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                index);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

OnResultActivityCode :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedFileURI = data.getData();
            File file = new File(selectedFileURI.getPath().toString());

            Log.i("", "File : " + file.getName());
            uploadedFileName = file.getName().toString();
            tokens = new StringTokenizer(uploadedFileName, ":");
            first = tokens.nextToken();
            file_1 = tokens.nextToken().trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Code to upload file :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("URL");


            if (file_1 != null && !file_1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath(), file_1);
                fileBody1 = new FileBody(file1);
            }

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);



            if (file_1 != null && !file_1.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody1);

            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {
                final String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)
                        .trim();
                Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseStr);
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            parseData(responseStr);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is error that I got when try to do with real device.

> 12-26 12:47:32.919: W/System.err(15529): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Woodenstreet Doc.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:491)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:92)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:206)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:224)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:183)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:97)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:162)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:272)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:242)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:592)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:512)
>       12-26 12:47:32.920: W/System.err(15529):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:490)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at com.cognus.gha.fragments.Fragment_Chat$PostDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(Fragment_Chat.java:498)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at com.cognus.gha.fragments.Fragment_Chat$PostDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(Fragment_Chat.java:1)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:477)
>       12-26 12:47:32.921: W/System.err(15529):    ... 22 more

Error  -

> 12-26 12:47:32.919: W/System.err(15529): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Woodenstreet Doc.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I am not able to whats the problem is that. Please help.

Comment: Does the file really exist? If yes, does the app have permission to access it?

Comment: What is the filename? why there's a space between `Woodenstreet ` and `Doc.doc`? Does `Woodenstreet ` part of path or the filename?

Comment: Yes, file exits and I gave permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE inside manifest.xml

Comment: File name  - WoodenStreet Doc.doc

Comment: Try removing space in name of file.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you getting wrong file path. Try this code to get file path and then change code and it works.

Use this code for get path of file.

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context ctx, Uri uri) {
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    Log.e("", "picturePath : " + picturePath);
    cursor.close();
    return picturePath;
}
```

And the change in your onActivityResult() code like this :

```
    getRealPathFromUri(getActivity(), selectedFileURI);
```

And finally use this in doInBackgraound() method

```
if (file_1 != null && !file_1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                file1 = new File(picturePath);
                fileBody1 = new FileBody(file1);
            }
```

Hope this will help you.