# Android Why this error ENOENT (No such file or directory) comes

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I want to know why this error comes when try to upload file with real device using Marshmallow. Can you please explain the solution for this.

> 12-28 10:39:32.606: E/3(17552): Excption : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/WoodenstreetD.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I was stuck with this for last week and still getting same issue.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please add your code..!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent .Check this link it's because of write protection of sd card

Comment: I ask question for this here is link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469351/getting-error-while-uploading-file-from-real-device-to-server

Comment: If the message of the exception claims that the specified file is a directory, then you must either alter the name of the file or delete the existing directory (if the directory is not being used by an application).

Comment: How may i do this, please suggest and help me. I am new to android.

Comment: i assume problem is here `file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath(), file_1);
                fileBody1 = new FileBody(file1);`

Comment: I did same already as you told, but not working

Comment: `file1` getting nothing .Print it first time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99090/discussion-between-coreand-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: String : WoodenstreetD.doc 
file : /storage/emulated/0/document/ECCA-8724:WoodenstreetD.doc 
 filebody 1 : org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody@350889e2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes due to wrong path. The path your getting from onActivityResult is not correct. Use this to get path of selected file.

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context ctx, Uri uri) {
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn,
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.e("", "picturePath : " + picturePath);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return picturePath;
}
```

picturePath gives you full path of image/file.

It'll work for me.

Comment: MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

i worte this and it'll work for me.

```
 public static java.io.File convertUriTFile(Activity activity, Uri uri) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        java.io.File file = null;
        try {
            inputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            file = new java.io.File(activity.getCacheDir(), "temp");
            try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                int read;

                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                output.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return file;

    }
```