# Where to store a read/write json file?

Tags: android

I want to have a JSON file where i can read and write data in my app. And i want to create the file during development. Not during the app download on the phone storage.
Since all file under /res are read-only where can i put my JSON file ? Certainly in the internal storage of my app but is it accessible from Android Studio?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use your app's internal storage

Comment: How can i drop a file in it from android studio ? I don't think this i feasible, there is no folder in android studio that is a read/write folder ?

Comment: You don't do it via the graphical interface - you create a file programmatically and write/read from it. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44587950/1219389)

Comment: Yes but the idea was to store some data directly during development and update them when user use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed a file with read/write permission in your APK.

I suggest you to embed a read-only file, in asset or raw folders for example, and at the first launch, you copy it into the internal storage to have a read/write version of the file.

Comment: Yes i think it's the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can store your file in the `res/raw` folder, right click `res` and add a new Resource Directory

[image]

Name your folder `raw`

[image]

Then, you can access your file like so:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("filename_without_ext",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Yes but i can't write in that file