# Writing to "Documents" folder on Android from Xamarin Forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to merge some txt-Files from a folder in a Xamarin Form app.

The path is selectable by the user (i´ve created a simple folder browser for that).

e.g. the source path is

```
/storage/1EE7-170F/
```

I collect e.g. all txt-files in that folder, read them using File.ReadAllText, do some processing.
That is working fine so far.

I also want to write the results to a new file in the same folder using File.WriteAllText. Target file would be:

```
/storage/1EE7-170F/SomeResultFile.txt
```

Getting the directories content is in AppName.Android:

```
var fileContents = Directory.GetFiles(baseDirectory.FullPath, searchPattern)
                    .Select(fullPath =>
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
                        return new FileContent(fileName, fullPath, extension);
                    });
```

Reading of the files goes like this in common project:

```
var content = File.ReadAllText(fileContent.FullPath);
```

The files are written like this (also in common project):

```
var baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFiles.First().FullPath);
var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(baseDir, filename); 
File.WriteAllLines(targetFilePath, lines);
```

But i always get an UnauthorizedAccessException saying 'Access to the path "/storage/1EE7-170F/SomeResultFile.txt" is denied.'

I wonder why i can read from that folder, but not write to it.

Writing to System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) is working fine, but that´s not what i need. 
I need the result files in the same directory as the source files.

I have both permission "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" enabled in the manifest.

In MainActivity.OnCreate i have added the following:

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
{
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
}

if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
{
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 0);
}
```

I´ve tried that both on Android emulator and a S10 with latest Android installed (on S10 i selected the "Documents" folder). Same result on both systems with different folders...

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Im pretty sure you can only write to the internal data directory of your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587187/android-how-to-write-a-file-to-internal-storage

Comment: Well, writing to a S10 internal Documents folder doesn't work either...

Comment: it would be helpful to see how you are writing the file then

Comment: Sure! I´ve added the code snippets to the original question for better readability...

Comment: If you want to wirte file to document folder, you should use `documents provider` to achieve that. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files  But, I suggest you to copy the file to the Download folder(`Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;`). Use `FileStream` to wirte it.

Comment: Update: I got it working by choosing a different folder. So i think i´ll restrict the chosen folder to that kind of folders that are working.

Thanks for all of your suggestions and hints!

Comment: I am gold to hear that you solved this issue, you are welcome.