# Android: how to save temporary file to disk?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a temporary file created like this :

```
File myfile = File.createTempFile(fileName + " - ", suffix, activity.getExternalCacheDir());
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file); 
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw, ' '/* DEFAULT_SEPARATOR */, NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, DEFAULT_LINE_END);
writer.writeNext(entries);
writer.close();
```

Now, I want to save it to disk at the URL /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myproject/files/myfile.csv

So I need to change the URL of myfile and save it to disk with code like this:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(myfile);
// How to change URL of myfile ?
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutput);
outputStreamWriter.flush();
fileOutput.getFD().sync();
outputStreamWriter.close();
```

How can I do that ? (= how to change URL and save to disk ?)

Thanks !

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(file)` That should be `new FileOutputStream(myFile)`. But... you should not have created that file already as new FileOutputSTream() will create the file. But it should not bother either.

Comment: I edited my question that was not detailed and accurate enough.

Comment: What you ask makes no sense. `Now, I want to save it to disk at the URL`. The code above that with FileWriter() did already save the csv in that file.

Comment: You are right... I get confused because I had another bug (very specific to my app) that disturbed me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save files to directories like **Android/data**  you should deal with external storage.

for api 28 and lower use this method :

[Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

[Read/Write String from/to a File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/read-write-string-from-to-a-file-in-android)

and for newer android devices like android 11 (api 29 and later) you should use scoped storage framework check this :

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

https://medium.com/microsoft-mobile-engineering/scoped-storage-in-android-10-android-11-28d58d989f3c

Otherwise you can save files to Internal Application folder or cache folder without permissions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127190/16728174

[Creating temporary files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425906/creating-temporary-files-in-android)

Do not forget to get proper Read/Write permission for these actions.