# Display all images from a specific directory

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm new to android. trying to create an app that allows the user to download a picture which is then stored in external storage,  My code is working fine but it is showing all images that are external storage. am im storing these pictures in a specific folder on the device, but I don't know how to display a list of all the pictures in that folder.

> like /storage/emulated/0/due/image/ only show this location pictures.
>
> If I write an image path, the application crashes.

my code

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
GridView gridView;
ArrayList<File> list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        checkPermissions();

        list = getImageFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + " /storage/emulated/0/due/image/"));

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              //  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class).putExtra("img", list.get(i).toString()));
            }
        });

    }

    class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return list.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_loader_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            //imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getItem(i).toString()));

            //Loading image from below url into imageView
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(getItem(i).toString())
                    .into(imageView);
            return view;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<File> getImageFiles(File root) {
        ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList();
        File[] files = root.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                list.addAll(getImageFiles(files[i]));
            } else {
                if(files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg") || files[i].getName().endsWith(".png") || files[i].getName().endsWith(".gif")) {
                    list.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return  list;
    }

    private void checkPermissions(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //Requesting permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override //Override from ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback Interface
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission granted
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private ActivityManager.MemoryInfo getMemoryInfo() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
        return memoryInfo;
    }


}
```

logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dueaoinfo.dueao_job/com.dueaoinfo.dueao_job.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.dueaoinfo.dueao_job.MainActivity.getImageFiles(MainActivity.java:91)
        at com.dueaoinfo.dueao_job.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
```

Comment: I do not see a path specified here about the **`image path`**.

Comment: @Sachin Bahukhand. I will not give the image path. if i  Writing an image path then the crash the application.

Comment: Check the log on why it crashes on providing it. Also provide the logcat output and set it to error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
list = getImageFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Can be replaced by:

```
  list = getImageFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/storage/emulated/0/due/image/");
```

So that it points to the folder you wish picking up.

References: [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40923081/5192105)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Post the logcat on entering the image path why it crashes. Also post the screenshot of the error.

Comment: The file array is null. Means there are no folders inside the folder.

Comment: Add the @NotNull annotation to the method `getImageFiles()`