# Room database is not importing and exporting

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am writing a program to backup and restore a room database in Android Studio. I have a recyclerview to load a user list. I am supposed to backup and restore the user list from the recyclerview to external storage. When I click the backup and restore buttons nothing happens. Please may anyone assist?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.innbucksbackuprestoreroomdb.database.AppDatabase;
import com.example.innbucksbackuprestoreroomdb.database.User;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.List;

public class BackupRestore extends AppCompatActivity {
    private UserListAdapter userListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.backup_restore);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initRecyclerView();

        loadUserList();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
    }

    private void loadUserList(){
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        List<User> userList = database.userDao().getallusers();
        userListAdapter.setUserList(userList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == 100){
            loadUserList();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public static void importDB(Context context) {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // by closing the database some other database files ending with -shm and -wal are deleted so that there is one database file and it has all content
            AppDatabase.getDbInstance(context).close();

            if (sd.canRead()) {
                File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);

                transfer(context, backupDB, currentDB);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Database Restored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void exportDB(Context context) {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // by closing the database some other database files ending with -shm and -wal are deleted so that there is one database file and it has all content
            AppDatabase.getDbInstance(context).close();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);
                transfer(context, currentDB, backupDB);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void transfer(Context context, File sourceFile, File destinationFile) throws IOException {
        if (sourceFile.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.back_up){
            BackupRestore.exportDB(getBaseContext());
        }
        else if(id == R.id.restore_btn){
            BackupRestore.importDB(getBaseContext());
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Code for the Userlist adapter:

```
public class UserListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<User> userList;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User>userList){
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(this.userList.get(position).getId()));
        holder.Name.setText(this.userList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.userList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView id;
        TextView Name;
        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            id = view.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            Name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ***When I click the backup and restore buttons nothing happens. Please may anyone assist?*** Then the first thing to try would be to place a BreakPoint on the line `File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` in both `exportDB` and `importDB` and then run in Debug mode. If the code does not stop and show the debug window when attempting to export/Import then the functions are not being called. If they are then you can follow the flow to see how far the code goes and what the code does/does not do. See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/.

Comment: context.getExternalFilesDir(null)

Comment: You may wish to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453708/android-how-to-use-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory and especially the comment with 45 useful points.

Comment: @MikeT I also suspect that there could be something wrong with my permissions because the code doesn't even ask for permissions