# Refresh Android mediastore using adb

Tags: android, adb, android-mediascanner

I'm using adb to sync music on an android phone. Essentially, I rm the existing music directory and push replacement music files.

I'd like to be able to use adb to force a rescan, so that the google music player (and other apps) works properly with the new songs and playlists.

According to [How can I refresh MediaStore on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300137/how-can-i-refresh-mediastore-on-android) you can force a rescan by broadcasting an appropriate intent.

adb provides 'shell am broadcast', which would seem to allow me to force a rescan from adb.

Alternatively I could run a rescan app or reboot, but I'd like to trigger the rescan from adb

What adb command should I issue?  The music files and playlists are all in /sdcard/music.

Answer (score 57):

The rescan apps use a media mount intent to kick off the media scanner. You can use `am broadcast` to send the same intent.

The command is:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard
```

Comment: I've been using: `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard/Music`

Comment: I noticed that on Kitkat the rescan doesn't happen right away, only eventually. I don't remember if that was the case on older APIs. Is there a way to force the rescan to happen immediately?

Comment: @foosion That works on my Nexus 6 running Android 5.1.1, 6.0, and 6.0.1.

Comment: @foosion That **does not work** on my Nexus 6 running Android N preview. I get a security exception.

Comment: @JaredBurrows it requires root on Nougat:  adb shell su -c 'am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard'

Comment: I got permission denied on android 7 but am rooted and this worked fine for me: `adb shell 'su -c "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard/Ringtones"'`

Comment: `adb shell am broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` seems to work now, without security exception

Answer (score 36):

The MEDIA_MOUNTED intent is no longer permitted (post KitKat) for non-system apps; try this instead.

It’s not recursive, though, and has to be run on the exact_file_name, so it’s not a good replacement.

```
adb shell am broadcast \
    -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE \
    -d file:///mnt/sdcard/Music/<exact_file_name>
```

If you need to rescan recursively, you can use this command (fix paths accordingly):

```
adb shell "find /mnt/sdcard/Music/ -exec am broadcast \
    -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE \
    -d file://{} \\;"
```

Or like this (if above won't work for you):

```
adb shell "find /mnt/sdcard/Music/ | while read f; do \
    am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE \
    -d \"file://${f}\"; done"
```

Comment: It's `android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`, not `android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`. ACTION_* is the name of the Android variable: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

Comment: None of these worked for me. This hack did, however: `adb shell '
    for ANDROID_MEDIA in $(find /mnt/sdcard/Music/ -type f | sed '\''s/ /\*/g'\''); do
        am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d "${ANDROID_MEDIA}"
    done
'`

Comment: I get broadcast completed result 0. And stock Moto gallery (Android 5.0) won’t find the picture I just moved from emulated/0 to /storage/sdcard1/Pictures. Why is that ? If I go to storage settings and choose move media to sdcard, then it works. It also works with  auto-move-to sdcard app.

Answer (score 2):

On some Samsung mobiles, you can get a full rescan like this:

```
am broadcast -a com.samsung.intent.action.MTP_FILE_SCAN -n com.android.providers.media/.MediaScannerReceiver
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Android, you can use `content call` to call the `scan_volume` method which achieves this:

```
adb shell content call --method scan_volume --uri content://media --arg external_primary
```

- `--method scan_volume` is the method to call [inside `MediaStore`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/providers/MediaProvider/apex/framework/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java;l=187;drc=02ad8f6802c36726104d961349c03319505ee909)
- `--uri content://media` refers to the content provider authority, in this case [`MediaStore.AUTHORITY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#AUTHORITY)
- `--arg external_primary` refers to name of the volume returned by [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory())

To verify it worked, you can use logcat:

```
adb logcat -s MediaProvider
```

Which in turn displays something like:

```
10-10 10:33:57.522  3261  3295 I MediaProvider: Scanned external_primary due to REASON_DEMAND, found 46 items in 325ms, 0 inserts 20 updates 0 deletes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have rooted your phone, you can use this script I’ve written, which has the advantage of keeping track of which files have already been updated:

```
#!/system/bin/env busybox ash

MUSIC_LIBRARY=/sdcard/MusicLibrary

LAST_UPDATE="$(stat -c %Y "$MUSIC_LIBRARY/.last-update")"

find "$MUSIC_LIBRARY" -type f ! -iname ".last-update" | (
  while read f; do
    if ! test "$LAST_UPDATE" -ge "$(stat -c %Y "$f")"; then
      am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d "file://$f"
      touch "$f"
    else
      echo "Not updated: \`$f'"
    fi
  done
)

touch "$MUSIC_LIBRARY/.last-update"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "touch" command *after* sending the broadcast?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work for poking Google Photos to find new pictures that have been rsynced to the device...

Comment: @Michael, the `touch` is there so that, on the next execution of the script, `! test ...` will return non-zero (*i.e.* "false", in the twisted world of shell scripts).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python script called `adb-scan`.
It uses `adb` to ask the Android device to rescan the given files.

Example usage:

```
$ adb-scan Notifications/\*.mp3
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=file:///sdcard/Notifications/cough.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=file:///sdcard/Notifications/harmonica3.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=file:///sdcard/Notifications/shhh.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
$
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# Ask the Android media scanner to check the given files.
#
import sys
import os
import re

sys.argv.pop(0)

if not sys.argv:
   sys.exit('usage: adb-scan files...')

intent = 'android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE'

# Quote certain special characters such as spaces, backslashes and quotes.  In
# particular, don't quote '*' because we want that to be expanded on the
# Android device.
def cleanup(arg):
   if not arg.startswith('/'):
      arg = '/sdcard/' + arg
   arg = re.sub("[ \\'\"]", lambda x: '\\' + x.group(0), arg)
   return arg

script = '''
for i in {args}; do
    [ -e "$i" ] || echo "warning: no such file: $i"
    am broadcast -a "{intent}" -d "file://$i"
done
'''.format(args=' '.join(map(cleanup, sys.argv)),
           intent=intent)

cmd = ['adb', 'shell', script]
os.execvp(cmd[0], cmd)
```