# Emulator : Dev tools has stopped on running media provider

Tags: android, ddms, devtools

I added few songs using DDMS and in the emulator opened Dev tools->Media Provider and ran scan SD card but got the error msg : Dev tools has stopped. Any idea how to resolve this ? I tried creating new AVD also both in Eclipse and Android Studio , Genymotion . But same results. Can anyone help on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

On API 23 Emulator you can go to Setting => App => Dev Tools => Permissions , and check the permissions

Answer (score 1):

Answering just in case it helps someone.

Giving permissions to Dev tools solves the issues sometimes but if it does not, one option is to download the files (songs or images) using browser on your emulator, if number of files is not much.

Worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the Nexus 5 image that comes with the latest version of Android Studio, the "Dev Tool" app does not declare the required `<uses-premission>` element in its manifest. If you filter the logcat by `com.android.developer` you will see this exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=2331, uid=10023`

Unfortunately there's not a lot you can do if you're not willing (or don't know how, as I admit I don't) to pull out the apk, unpack it, edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and pack it all back in. Use another image, or refresh the MediaStore using `adb shell`:

[Refresh Android mediastore using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928576/refresh-android-mediastore-using-adb)