# android update storage content database

Tags: android

I'm developing Android music player. I query music using content provider api. My Android phone(nexus 6p) has no music in sdcard storage. So I upload many songs I downloaded from computer using `adb push * /sdcard/Music` shell  command. It uploaded successfully. But when query using content provider api.Query result is empty. So I reboot my nexus 6p. I query again. It query all songs uploaded successfully.

So my question is how to update storage database for content provider api to query without reboot Android Phone! Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean through adb? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928576/refresh-android-mediastore-using-adb

Comment: Yes. I go to this link. But a security problem happened. java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=17238, uid=2000

Comment: Have a look at [this answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902912).

Comment: Yes. I think I should root my nexus 6p

Comment: That answer doesn't mention anything about rooting, though I've not tested it.