# ContentResolver running on Emulator can't find mp3 Files

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-contentprovider

I use a contentResolver Query on my Android Studio Emulator. I put the mp3 files in the downloads folder, where I can see them int the android studio device file explorer and in den device exporer in the emulator.
I can't fetch the files using contentResolver Query.

```
String sortOder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK + " ASC";
cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, sortOder);
```

The ContentResolver is searching for `content://media/external/audio/media`

I restarted the emulator, removed and installed the app after upload.

On real devices this resolver works, but not on the emulator.
Why does the contentResolver on the emulator doesn't find the uploaded files.

Thanks
GGK[image]

Comment: Presumably, they have not been indexed by the `MediaStore`.

Comment: ok, and how to index them? though recreation of the app does new indexing

Comment: Eventually, they should get indexed. You could try rebooting the emulator (simulating a real reboot, not just closing and reopening the window) and see if they get reindexed automatically. Normally, the code that puts the files out on external storage will index them at that point.

Comment: no, rebooting the emulator doesn't reindexing. Problem persists

Comment: You can try [a solution like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902912/115145) to reindex via `adb`.

Comment: I've tried these solutions... but I got a Permission Denial error (not allowed to broadcast). I don't think my problem is due to the non-indexed mediastore because the emulator exporter finds the files.

Comment: Problem problem only occurs under API29. I have created a new entry for this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586601/contentresolver-running-on-emulator-cant-find-mp3-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reboot your devices if you just dragged your files into the sdcard in Android Studio. It's not updated immediately.