# How should I upload files to Android Automotive?

Tags: android, adb, automotive

I'm using a tablet running a Snapp image of the AAOS. I have tried **adb push** to

*/storage/self/primary/Download*

and to

*/sdcard/Download/*

While the second one works ( it is possible to see the files browsing through the shell ), I can not see them on the GUI ( see screenshot below ). Any suggestions?

[image]

As most posts suggest, I tried adb push unsuccessfully

Comment: Most likely the program you use in GUI doesn't use the file-system but the AndroidMediaDatabase (scoped storage) which uses a database. If that database is out of sync with the file-system you don't see the files uploaded via `adb`. Newer Android versions automatically sync the DB based on file-system operations, older Android versions need to manually forced to do so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928576/refresh-android-mediastore-using-adb