# Android MediaStore Not Showing New Recorded Sound File

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, mediastore

I am creating a voice recording application using the tutorial here.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm

I am then using

```
    Intent Intent = new Intent();
    Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    Intent.setData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the intent
    startActivityForResult(Intent, 1);
```

To display the list of audio files.
The recorded file does not show up in this list straight away, but after a while it does.

I think I need to refresh the media store or something, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks

**Solution**
Whenever the new file is saved, let the MediaStore Content Provider know.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(soundFileThatWasAdded)));
```

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/14849652/1524450 can be of help.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working :). I have updated the question with the solution.