# Cordova: file not found after move/copy (ios & android)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, html5-filesystem, file-uri

I'm recording/selecting video with media-capture plugin, convert it to mp4 with video-editor plugin and after the user confirms the selection I copy/move this file to app specific media dir (something like `/storage/emulated/0/APPNAME/Video/`).

Everything works fine, except that if the user tries to open the video file immediately, the native video player will open but there'll be a message like "Could not play video" (on android) and the `console.log` shows the error "File not found".

This happens on both iOS and Android.
I use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/org.vaadin.alump.openfile) plugin to open video files in native players.

If I exit the app and reopen it, the issue dissapears. So the problem is, I think, that the system does not know about the existance of that new copied/moved file. Is there a way to refresh the filesystem?

I have checkd the file URI that I pass to the openfile plugin and it's the same when it works & when it doesn't.

I use HTML5 FileSystem to copy/move files.

I use promisses, I wait until files are copied/moved, so it's not this the issue.

Comment: There is a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300137/how-can-i-refresh-mediastore-on-android/3309940#3309940) that might help.