# Android see created folders on file explorer

Tags: java, android

I am creating folder with following code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
    this.showDialog("Done");
}
else{
    this.showDialog("Exist");
}
```

This code show Exist and Done correctly, but when I go to sd card with file explorer, I cannot see created folders. Why and how to make it work?

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300137/how-can-i-refresh-mediastore-on-android).

Comment: @LymZoy could not find related topic to create directory

Comment: `f.mkdirs();
    this.showDialog("Done");`. Pretty bad code. mkdirs can fail and if so will return false. So adapt your code and your toasts.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of file explorer you use.

Comment: You can try to offer your created directory as an `File` instance, and use the most-upvoted answer.

Comment: @LymZoy for example i installed my phone with cable to my computer and i can not see that folder

Comment: `this.showDialog("Exist");`. Not very informative. Exists what? Inform the user and yourself with `this.showDialog("Exists: " + f.getAbsolutePath());`.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, try this(make sure `f` currently doesn't exist):

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists() && f.mkdirs()) {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(f)));
    this.showDialog("Done");
}else{
    this.showDialog("Exist");
}
```