# Android file.delete() returns true but file still exist in gallery

Tags: android, delete-file

I want to delete some images from my phone. I have image path and I simply do this

```
try {
    File file = new File(content);
    if (file.canRead()) {
        boolean mDeleleFile = file.delete();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(content))));
        if (mDeleleFile) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even if I get File deleted when I open gallery image still exist! Why is that? What I'm missing?

Comment: You are creating new file while sending broadcast

Comment: I've tried without sendBroadcast but still file exist...

Comment: Are you check your path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300137/how-can-i-refresh-mediastore-on-android/14849652#14849652

Answer (score 0):

your may have created a new file after deleting it.