# 'ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE:String' is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

```
activity?.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(copyFile)))
```

I got the warning

> ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE is deprecated.

in above code

Is there a simple replacement code?

Answer (score 36):

ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE Deprecated!

You can use the following

Java

```
File file = new File(filePath);
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                    new String[]{file.toString()},
                    null, null);
```

Kotlin

```
val file = File(filePath) 
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(file.toString()),
      null, null)
```

This will request the media scanner to scan the files at the specified path. Also, it is worth noticing that 3rd and 4th param in scanFile() method is null in the above example. However the third param can be used to optionally specify the MIME TYPE of the file and the fourth param can be used to supply a listener to listen to the scan completion event.

[Refer developer site for details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener))

Following is the deprecated way

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
```

Comment: how to remplace this : `private fun galleryAddPic() {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).also { mediaScanIntent ->
            val f = File(currentPhotoPath)
            mediaScanIntent.data = Uri.fromFile(f)
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
        }`

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo In the above answer, file is the File object so in your case, it would be like following : 
val f = File(currentPhotoPath) 
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(f.toString()),
      arrayOf(f.getName()), null)
Cheers!

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo Added File class object in my answer as well to make things more clear.

Comment: I don't get it.. why do you pass 'new String[]{file.getName()}' as mimeTypes parameter (3rd one)? see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)

Comment: @Niteshgoyal Well, 3rd argument is 'new String[]{file.getName()}' which is not null. Fourth argument is null, but that's the callback argument.
I guess the example should be this: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                    new String[]{file.toString()},
                    null ,null);

Comment: @Pascal I have updated my answer.
To answer your question, the third parameter is to specify the mime type of the file that we are providing.
But this param is optional and can be null, as android will infer the mime type from the file extension if null is passed for the third parameter.

Or if we want to specify the mime type then it could be passed based on the file mime type
For e.g. File file = new File(filePath);
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                    new String[]{file.toString()},
                    new String[] { "video/*" }, null);

Comment: @Pascal thanks for noticing it, I wonder how come no one noticed it so far including myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Media Store API passing it to the resolver will already trigger a media scan. Here an example for an image:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "test.jpg")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) // requires API level 29
}


// this also adds it to the gallery
contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
```

Answer (score -1):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

> This constant was deprecated in API level 29. Callers should migrate to inserting items directly into MediaStore, where they will be automatically scanned after each mutation