# How to update Android MediaStore in time by lua script?

Tags: javascript, java, android, shell, lua

The lua script will download pictures and videos on your Android phone, you need to restart your phone to find it. After searching for related information, I found that it is related to MediaStore, but the lua script code does not know how to write it. can you help me? Thank you

Comment: The lua script lacks some code. But do you know what should be done by the missing code?

Comment: A normal file explorer app will show the files without reboot. So you can find them.

Comment: Figure out in what environment the Lua script is running (Termux, custom interpreter, rooted device) and then research how to update MediaStore in that environment.

Comment: May be it will give you some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849652/12918181

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on you:

```
path = userPath().."/res/1.mp4"
os.execute("am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file://"..path)
```